# How to mark up structured data that is visible upon click with microdata

Tags: seo

I have a site that lists several items per page. When the user clicks he can see each item's prices (a list of about 10-20). They are not visible at first because the page will be very long.

I want to tag them with the offers schema.org microdata structure. 
How can I make this tagging seo friendly? Is it only possible if each product has its own page? 
Items are dynamic and change every week that's why I figured its not good to have a dedicated page for each (and also for user experience).

Comment: Unsure if this belongs to webmasters exchange. If a mod thinks that's the case please move it.